# Threads design when need both: wait and continue

Tags: c#, multithreading

.Hi, I need to run every task `T` in the `Tasklist` in different thread, and when every T finish, do `something` Without bothering the main program or anther threads.
[And I cann't change the `myTask.runTask()` method ]

Can you suggest me the correct design to do it?

```
foreach (myTask T in this.TaskList)
{
    if (T.NextRunTime<=Now);
        new Thread(() => T.runTask()).Start(); //When done: Do 'something'...
        //do more stuff                   
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
class Program
  {
   static List<Task>  allTasks = new List<Task>();
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        foreach (myTask T in this.TaskList)
            {
       if (T.NextRunTime<=Now);
               var task=  Task.Factory.StartNew(() => T.runTask().Start());
                 task.ContinueWith( delegate
                                              {
                                                  //code  for your continuation 
                                                  //you can call the method for doing this  
                                              },TaskContinuationOptions.NotOnFaulted);

                 try
                 { // and here to handle all  your exceptions  
                     task.Wait();

                 }
                 catch (AggregateException ae)
                 {

                     ae.Handle((x) =>
                     {

                         return true;
                     });

                 }
            }
        //you can even try someting  like this  
        // Task.WaitAll(allTasks.ToArray());  
    }
}
```

Comment: hey, @BRAHIM Kamel. I used your's solution and it seems like it worked. Q: The `Task`s working async?

Comment: yes  it's  something like  async await concept introduced in .NET 4.5

Answer (score 1):

Use `Task` with a call to `.ContinueWith(...)` to specify code to execute upon completion of the task's execution

```
        foreach (myTask T in this.TaskList)
        {
            if (T.NextRunTime<=Now)
            {
                var task = new Task( T.runTask() );
                task.ContinueWith( <Action to execute on task completion> );
                task.Start();
            }                 
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Just start a new `Task` for each task that you want to run and then use `WhenAll` to execute code when they have all run.

```
var tasks = TaskList.Where(task => task.NextRunTime <= Now)
    .Select(task => Task.Run(() => task.runTask()));

task.WhenAll(tasks)
    .ContinueWith(t => {
        //do stuff
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var threads = this.TaskList
    .Where(t => t.NextRunTime <= Now)
    .Select(t => new Thread(() => { t.runTask(); /* Do 'something' */ }))
    .ToList();

threads.ForEach(t => t.Start());
threads.ForEach(t => t.Join());
//do more stuff (all threads finished)
```

Comment: Thanks @Jakub Konecki. If I want to "//do more stuff" without wait to any of the threads, I just need to remove the Join loop, right?

Comment: @Yaron - yes, you can move it before the loop so it executes right after the other threads start

Comment: It's much better to use the TPL to manage the tasks.  You, of course, *can* spin up that many threads at once; but the TPL will throttle thread creation so you don't create all the threads at once if there aren't enough cores/cpus to handle it.  i.e. if you create more threads than you have cores, you will introduce context switching and make it run *slower* than if you used less threads.

Comment: @PeterRitchie - That depends on what the threads are doing. If threads are mostly waiting (ie, I/O) than you might want to spin more than the number of cores as your CPU won't be fully utilised.

Comment: @JakubKonecki Honestly, that's a tired-old excuse for simply starting up a bunch of threads.  the assumption *should be* that the threads are CPU bound.  Starting up a bunch of threads to simply "Wait" is poor design to start with--let alone opening the possibility of lots of context switches (i.e. *not* scalable).  RE IO: creating a thread per IO operation is also poor design--use async IO (or overlapped IO in native)--an "idle" thread still uses resources.

Comment: @PeterRitchie let's agree to disagree. I've done a fair bit of multi-threaded apps that use DB heavily (bulk inserts, more than 100ms queries) and I could get a better total throughput by spinning more threads than cores. Context-switching is peanuts comparing to network/db latency.

Comment: @JakubKonecki before TPL I would have agreed with you.  with TPL you now have an option that is more maintainable and more scalable.